# How to mask certain cell's info from a gtsummary table

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have some sensitive info in my data that I need to hide below a certain threshold (to comply with DUA and prevent reidentifying data). I'm using `tbl_svysmmary()` from `gtsummary`. In my example, I like to filter "cell size ≤ 100":

```
library(gtsummary)
library(survey)

tbl_svysummary <-
  svydesign(~1, data = as.data.frame(Titanic), weights = ~Freq) %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = Survived, percent = "row", include = c(Class, Age))

tbl_svysummary
```

[image: Characteristic No, N = 1,4901 Yes, N = 7111 Class 1st 122 (38%) 203 (62%) 2nd 167 (59%) 118 (41%) 3rd 528 (75%) 178 (25%) Crew 673 (76%) 212 (24%) Age Child 52 (48%) 57 (52%) Adult 1,438 (69%) 654 (31%) 1 n (%)]

---

I want to show child info as:

[image: Child cell size≤100 cell size≤100]

---

EDIT: Reproducible example for multiple stat_ columns and 0/1 variables:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(survey)

supp_outcomes <-
  as.data.frame(Titanic) %>% 
  mutate (Female=ifelse(Sex=="Female",1,0)) %>%   
  svydesign(~1, data = ., weights = ~Freq) %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = Survived, percent = "row", 
                 include = c(Age, Female, Class)) %>% 
  add_overall() %>% add_p()

supp_outcomes
```

The edited code from @Marco's suggested solution:

```
supp_outcomes$table_body <- supp_outcomes$table_body %>% 
  mutate(extra1 = stat_0,
         extra2 = stat_1,
         extra3 = stat_2) %>% 
  separate(extra1, c("number"), sep = ' \\(') %>% 
separate(extra2, c("number"), sep = ' \\(') %>% 
separate(  extra3, c("number"), sep = ' \\(') %>% 
  mutate(number = as.numeric(number)) %>% 
  mutate(stat_0 = case_when(
    number < 200 & number > 0 & var_type %in%c("dichotomous", "categorical")~ "TOO FEW",
    TRUE ~ stat_0),
    stat_1 = case_when(
      number < 200 & number > 0 & var_type %in%c("dichotomous", "categorical")~ "TOO FEW",
      TRUE ~ stat_1),
    stat_2 = case_when(
      number < 200 & number > 0 & var_type %in%c("dichotomous", "categorical")~ "TOO FEW",
      TRUE ~ stat_2)) %>% 
  select(!number)

supp_outcomes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do more `tidyverse` manipulation on the output object like this (using the `table_body`):

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

library(gtsummary)
output <- mtcars[,1:2] %>% tbl_summary() 

output$table_body

# A tibble: 5 × 6
  variable var_type    var_label row_type label stat_0           
  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr>            
1 mpg      continuous  mpg       label    mpg   19.2 (15.4, 22.8)
2 cyl      categorical cyl       label    cyl   NA               
3 cyl      categorical cyl       level    4     11 (34%)         
4 cyl      categorical cyl       level    6     7 (22%)          
5 cyl      categorical cyl       level    8     14 (44%)  

# Don't show cell information when N of cyl is less than 10
output$table_body <- output$table_body %>% 
  mutate(extra = stat_0) %>% 
  separate(extra, c("number"), sep = ' \\(') %>% 
  mutate(number = as.numeric(number)) %>% 
  mutate(stat_0 = case_when(number < 10 & var_type == "categorical" ~ "TOO FEW",
                            TRUE ~ stat_0)) %>% 
  select(!number)

output
```

The filter decision in `case_when` is based on categorical variables, where you like to control the cell information, when it is less than a threshold value. You can adjust this for any other variable or condition.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work on binary cells with 0-1
Also, I wonder how can we make this work on `all stat_` columns
I had to edit your code to include dichotomous variables and repeat the code you gave for all stat variables manually, I'd appreciate a better way (more efficient) to do it. Thanks. Note:

I made an edit to include my table with multiple columns and 0/1 variables

Comment: Can you better describe your setup and data. I would suggest if you do this for say 1 or 2 tables and one or two variables, pick those values manually. We could code a more general approach, but what is the use-case? Do you have to report 50 tables all with very limited numbers that you cannot show?